# Tailwind CSS Group is not working in custom classes

Tags: tailwind-css

I am trying to build a dropdown with `tailwind CSS(v2.2.15)` `group and group-hover` classes. It works fine when I use them in HTML directly. But when I use it in custom class with @apply it doesn't work.

Custom classes:

```
.dropdown-container {
    @apply group inline-block relative;
}

.dropdown-list {
    @apply absolute
    hidden
    -left-16
    top-0
    rounded-lg
    text-sm
    group-hover:block;
}
```

but if I use the `group` in HTML directly it works fine. I also extend the group hover for display in `tailwind.config.js`

tailwind.config.js

```
  variants: {
    extend: {
      display: ['group-hover']
    }
  },
```

Is it possible to use this feature in custom class

Answer (score 1):

I had issues using `group-hover` inside `@apply`, so i just used vanilla css

```
.parent-class:hover .child-class {
@apply your-tailwind-classes
}
```

---

If you want to use `custom classes` when using `group-hover` inside the template:

in `css` file

```
@tailwind utilities;

@layer utilities {
  .hover-small { @apply your--tailwind-classes; // or normal css }
  .hover-large { @apply your--tailwind-classes; // or normal css }
}
```

in html just use `group-hover` with these `custom` utilities

```
<span class="handle transition duration-300 
rounded-full group-hover:custom-hover-small">
</span>
```

In my case i needed dynamic class depending on the `size` prop

```
<span class="handle transition duration-300 rounded-full" 
:class="`group-hover:hover-${size}`">
</span>
```

but for that to work i had to add these specific classes in `tailwind.config.js` safelist so its pre-generates it

```
safelist: ['group-hover:hover-small', 'group-hover:hover-large'],
```

Answer (score -1):

This doesn't answer your exact question, but tailwind provide a huge bunch of pre-built components you can just cut and paste to save reinventing the wheel: https://tailwindcomponents.com/components/dropdowns